# Why is the COVID-19 death rate so high in San Marino?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

San Marino has a COVID-19 death rate of 943 per million population (third column from left):

[image]
— [Coronavirus Update (Live): 1,256,358 Cases and 68,229 Deaths from COVID-19 Virus Outbreak - Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) (April 5)

This is more than 100 times the reported 8.8 global average.

It actually exceeds the rates of *the next 4 highest countries combined*.

Is this extreme difference merely a statistical anomaly due to the country's relatively small population, or is there something fundamentally different happening there?

Comment: You should include the demographic of that population in particular age groups.